# C++ MPFRC++ How to use memcpy() with mpfr::mpreal?

Tags: c++, memcpy, mpfr

I couldn't find anything related to this question. Suppose I have two `mpfr::mpreal` arrays, `a` and `b`, in the heap, as `new mpfr::mpreal[n]`. I have to use C-style arrays because of a function that calls and uses the arrays. I can't modify it, I tried, but it gives wrong results, plus crashes, it's a fairly big and complicated function for my level. If the arrays can get large (both size and type/precision), I'd like to avoid a loop for copying and I'd like to use `memcpy()` instead. What should I use as the 3rd argument?

I tried `sizeof(mpfr::mpreal)` but it always gives `32`, no matter what I use in `mpfr_set_default_prec()`. In the home page I have seen that I can use `mpfr::machine_epsilon()` to better display this, but how can I use it in `memcpy()`?

Comment: `I'd like to avoid a loop for copying and I'd like to use memcpy() instead`. It is not a good idea. mpfr uses big integers for the mantissa and is likely to alloc some part of the information in the heap. Such information is not intended to be shared among different `mpreal` - to avoid double free errors.

Comment: I didn't know how they were handled under the hood, but that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mpfr::mpreal` variable (or array of them) is C++ object, it cannot be copied by `memcpy` correctly. Use std::copy or loop instead.

The `memcpy` just copies memory blocks bit-by-bit, which works fine for simple POD C-style data structures. C++ objects should be copied by calling the assignment operator so that object can take care of memory allocations, etc. by itself.

The size of `mpfr::mpreal` is always the same since it just contains pointer to mantissa, which is allocated in heap in different memory location. The `memcpy` copies just the pointer, it doesn't reallocate mantissa and thus source and destination mpreals will point to the same mantissa in memory. This is exactly what should be avoided. In turn, `std::copy` takes care of this well - by copying every object in a loop using assignment operator of mpreal class (which does the necessary reallocations, etc.)

(I am author of MPFR C++).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The reason I asked was because I saw, very recently, a page where it showed that, un-optimized code was a lot slower for array copying than `memcpy()` (also did a quick verify myself). Optimized, the performances were similar for certain compilers. All in all, I'll just choose the loop, as it seems the most straight-forward thing to do. I don't particularly like `std::copy` or anything written under the hood because of the general use they were made for and the (slight) overhead that brings for particular cases, such as mine.